# A multiple movement of the cursor

Tags: cursor-movement

For example the code below,

```
1: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
3: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The arrow key moves the cursor from one character to the left, right, up, and down. If I want to move two or multiple movements at one time, how it is achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: See `:help Q_lr` for (some) more motions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prefix them with a number like the other mouvements `j` or `l`.

`2<down>` move 2 lines down like `2j`